# How can I add a list of text items to the end of another list of text items?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, sublime-text-3

I have 150 lines of text which looks something like this:

```
select * from my_table where name =
select * from my_table where name =
select * from my_table where name =
select * from my_table where name =
...
```

I have another 150 lines of text which looks like this:

```
James
Mikayla
John
Sarah
Frank
...
```

I need to add each of those names **one name per line, respectively** to the end of each of those previous statements. The key here is that *I am not trying to add the SAME piece of text to the end of each line, but rather different unique words to each line, respectively*. I have 150 statements and 150 names. I have Notepad++ and Sublime Text. How could I do this? Thanks. *Note that this isn't a SQL question and the SQL was made up to illustrate the point. The actual query I need to run isn't this simple and cannot be combined.*

Comment: At a guess, for Notepad++, your best bet would be to use the [Python Script plugin](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) and try to write your own solution. Currently (as of version 1.0.8.0), it uses an older version of the Python language (2.7.6) internally (which has potential syntax implications) but is otherwise functional. That said, if you're going that route, you might be just as good (or better, depending on needs) with writing a reusable standalone script with a vanilla installation of [Python](https://www.python.org).

Answer (score 0):

In [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) editor (and others) you have "vertical blocks". Select block with mouse with holded Alt key. On Linux, Alt is reserved, so use keys Shift+Alt+arrows.

Then copy this block to cliboard and paste it after "=" at first line. If lines of not equal length, paste it after longest position of "=" char.